# How to count the number of possible graphs?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose we have a random graph on $n$ vertices. (Each possible edge is included with some probability).

How many ways can we potentially find $2$ copies of $K_4$ the complete graph on $4$ vertices that are not disjoint (i.e they share at least one edge)?

Here is what I have so far:

I think there is only two possible situations they share $2$ vertices or they share $3$ vertices since if they share $4$ then they are the same graph.

If they share $2$ vertices then the number of ways to possibly do this is $n\choose4$$4\choose2$$n-2\choose2$, that is the number of ways to pick the first complete graph, the number of ways to pick the $2$ vertices that are shared and the number of ways to pick the two remaining vertices.

In the second case we argue similarly to get $n\choose4$$n-4\choose1$$4\choose3$.

Is this correct?

Comment: You are close.  Are you sure you are not double counting anything?

Comment: @deinst I have just had another think about it and think the answers should be $n\choose2$$n-2\choose4$ and $n\choose3$$n-3\choose2$ respectively. Do you agree?

Comment: Do $n=6$ by hand.  How many configurations do you find?

Comment: See my answer in the comment above I think this is correct. For $n=6$ I believe they agree. Example: In the first case we have $n\choose2$ this is the number of possible edges. Then once you have chosen this edge you have completely determined what the graph will look like (since we need all pairs of vertices to share an edge).

I think this is correct but if you disagree could you explain what you get and where my argument fails?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem seems to have little to do with the overall random graph. It is rather just to count th enumber of (ordered?) pairs of 4-element subsets that have 2 or 3 elements in common ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each possible edge is included with some probability

I’ll assume that ‘some‘ means non-zero.

My experience suggests that it is easier and more didactic to count accurately and clearly (and simply) than to debug a not so accurate and clear counting for errors.

I’ll be straightforward. Let $V’$ be the vertex sets of the union of two intersecting copies of $K_4$. The following distinct cases are possible.

$|V’|=6$. Then there are ${n \choose 6}$ cases to choose $V’$. In this case the copies of $K_4$ have exactly $2$ common vertices. There are  ${6 \choose 2}$ possibilities to choose these $2$ vertices, and ${4 \choose 2}$ possibilities to split remaining  $4$ vertices into two pairs (for each of the copies)(I count a number of ordered pairs of copies, which is twice bigger than the number of the non-ordered pairs).

$|V’|=5$. Then there are ${n \choose 5}$ cases to choose $V’$. In this case the copies of $K_4$ have exactly $3$ common vertices. There are  ${5 \choose 3}$ possibilities to choose these $3$ vertices, and ${2 \choose 1}$ possibilities to split remaining  $2$ vertices 
for each of the copies.

Thus the total number of ordered pairs for $n\ge 6$ is

$${n \choose 6}{6 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}+{n \choose 5}{5 \choose 3}{2 \choose 1}=$$
$$\frac{n!}{(n-6)!6!}\cdot\frac{6!}{4!2!}\cdot\frac{4!}{2!2!}+\frac{n!}{(n-5)!5!}\cdot\frac{5!}{3!2!}\cdot\frac{2!}{1!1!}=$$
$$\frac{n!}{8\cdot (n-6)!}+\frac{n!}{6\cdot (n-5)!}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Different approach: For such $K_4$s, let $A$ be the set of vertices belonging to the first, but not second $K_4$; let $B$ be the set of vertices belonging to the second, but not first $K_4$; let $C$ be the set of vertices shared by both. So for the pairwise disjoint sets $A,B,C$ we have $2\le |C|\le 3$, $|A|=|B|=4-|C|$. Let $a=|A|$, so $a=1$ or $a=2$. For fixed $a$, we have $n\choose a$ ways to pick $A$, then $n-a\choose a$ ways to pick $B$, then $n-2a\choose 4-a$ ways to pick $C$.
So in total we have
$$\begin{align}&{n\choose 1}{n-1\choose 1}{n-2\choose 3} + {n\choose 2}{n-2\choose 2}{n-4\choose 2}\\{}={}&
\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)}{6} +\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)}{8} \\
{}={}&\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(3n-11)}{24}\\
{}={}&5\cdot (3n-11)\cdot {n\choose 5}
\end{align}$$
You should note that when adding your results, you ought to arrive at the same final result. However, you have (at least in the expressions you wrote in the question) a tiny mistake in the expression for two shared vertices, so maybe double-check that one.

(Of course, if you are interested in *unordered* pairs, you have to divide this number by $2$).